# Difficulty making reset button work for pedometer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors

I am working on a pedometer and it runs smoothly. I want to make a button for resetting but its giving me issues.

This is my code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private TextView textView;
private Button resetButton;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mStepCounterSensor;
private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor;


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pedometer);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
}


public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
   float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
        textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
    } else if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {

        textView.setText("Step Detector Detected : " + value);
    }
}
//check this reset
public void reset(SensorEvent event){
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = 0;


    }

    if (sensor.getType() == value) {
        textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
    }
}

protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor,

            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor);
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepDetectorSensor);
}
}
```

I am connecting the reset method to my button so that when I click it. It resets my pedometer to zero. I have tried different ways but it is not working for me.
I am also unsure because my teacher has taught me to use View v in the parameters. I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: where are you calling your reset method. via xml???

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code is not clear.

```
if (sensor.getType() == value) {
        textView.setText("Step Counter Detected : " + value);
    }
```

1. Why are you comparing sensor type with value? You have to compare with Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR or Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER.
2. value is a local variable. So I am assuming you are resetting only for display purpose.
3. Who is calling reset() function and how is the SensorEvent passed to it?